# Facebook user data encryption

Tags: tls

In my country, Austria, a telecommunications data retention law will be executed starting at April 1. Internet carriers are required to store connection data (from which computer to which server), but no actual data payloads, for up to 6 months.

I would like to avoid the government knowing which of the many million Facebook profiles is mine (I'm using a pseudonym as name). AFAIK, SSL encrypts the GET-parameters as well, so my profile id should be safe from storing. Is there any other way the government could find out about my FB profile id, given only the connection data?

If yes, is the only way to keep my profile safe to always use a VPN?

Comment: @manmal - There is very little you can do if your ISP is recording what domains you vist unless you use an encrypted vpn connection.

Comment: For example they could ask facebook giving them your IP.

Comment: "given only the connection data", and not content, there would not be a way to determine which account was logged into.

Comment: @schroeder - I think the objective of storing the connection data is to be able to use it to subpoena information from facebook or anybody else. So if from subpoenaing the ISP they know you logged into facebook with a given IP at a given time, they can require facebook to tell you which account was logged in to.

Comment: @schroeder: Not directly, no. Alas, traffic analysis can give you *lots* of indirect hints; with enough indirect data, you can make a pretty accurate picture of who did what when and where. For a very simple example: "after loading a page from Facebook's server, the user loaded a page from example.com's server? Hmm, let's see who posted or liked a link to example.com at Facebook lately...see if it isn't our man"

Comment: @Piskvor yep, of course, but the OP was pretty specific. Without SSL, they could inspect the connection data and find login info. With SSL, then they need the supplementary data that you indicate.

Comment: @schroeder: Yes, and? If I understand this correctly, *the bill requires the ISPs to log **all** connections*, not just those going to FB. From correlating the connections coming from one IP address, it would be possible to identify likely FB users. There is no supplementary data involved. The question was "Is there any other way the government could find out about my FB profile id, given only the *connection data?*" - not "Is there a way the government can find about my FB profile given only the data for connections going *directly to FB's servers*?"

Comment: @schroeder: As for "without SSL" - it's not a magic security dust. Two words: DigiNotar+sslstrip (how many "trusted CAs" are there in an average browser?). I'm aware, however, that it would be a much more involved attack (and very likely to be deemed illegal, should a government try this and get caught; data mining seems legally acceptable in the original scenario). Plus, not everyone uses SSL - FB does, do the sites *linked* from FB? (Mostly not; there goes a nice and juicy `Referer` header.)

Comment: @Piskvor I totally understand that the idea is to log all connections. But indirect inference does not, in my imagination, seem plausible to determine a specific FB profile. Could you break that down further for me? How does clicking a linked site on FB increase the opportunity to determine a FB account? Also, your sslstrip example does not apply for log analysis.

Comment: @schroeder: The sslstrip is a different case, yes. Now, with enough data ("What other sites were also visited from this IP address? What do we know about this user in RL? Does the RL profile match the IP visited site profile?"), the potential IP-to-person matches will start to stand out. Not after one hour of browsing, and perhaps not after a day of browsing; but in a few weeks, you'll have a nice big pile of data to mine, and then the person-to-IP maps will start to stand out, using basic statistical analysis.

Comment: @Piskvor I'm totally cool with the idea that you can trace back all that traffic data to a real person. But I am still not sure how you are applying your process to determine a match of a fake FB profile to a real person. Can you lay it out clearly and make it an answer? Your reasoning would be directly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @schroeder: Depends on what you mean by "fake" - if this is a profile used consistently and exclusively by one person, it is the link between this account and this person which is interesting. The fact that the profile info says "Piskvor Notarealname" and doesn't match the legal name (and other data) of the person using it is quite irrelevant.

Comment: @Piskvor yes, I meant 'pseudonym'. How to infer a connection between a pseudonym'ed FB profile and a real person through ISP logs. Can you lay it all out for the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ISP is only storing the header data, information letting them know that the connection occurred, when it occurred, how long it was, and how much data was transmitted they can't tie you to a Facebook account based on that information alone.

However, they could subpoena Facebook for any logs they have tied to your IP address and determine your account from there.

If you want to be as anonymous as possible I would recommend giving Tor a try.  It is a project that allows users to bounce their traffic through several nodes located around the world while no single node is capable of determining the source and destination of the traffic.  Specifically try the Tor browser bundle (Google is in friend for finding it).  It provides fairly strong anonymity, but make sure you use SSL still because the node that your traffic goes through to reach the rest of the internet will see it unencrypted if you don't and they have been known to log traffic in the past.

In short, with Tor you can hide (even from your ISP) the fact that your IP address connected to Facebook at some point in time.  Beyond that, theres not much you can do.

Comment: I am using ExpressVPN and I'm quite satisfied with that, no need to burden Tor with my tremendous traffic amounts :) Thing is, I don't want to always have VPN enabled, as I've done nothing wrong. The first part of your answer was what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: If your using something like that, then the government would have to subpoena ExpressVPN for your traffic history.  The ISP wouldn't even know you were going to Facebook, the only thing that would show up in their logs is traffic going to ExpressVPN.